# Spacemacs evil-insert at start of line? (Emacs Evil Mode)

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, evil-mode

I finally got this to work, but wanted to know if there was an easier way.

I want to bind a key "U" to put spacemacs into insert-mode, but at the start of the text of the line.

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "u" 'evil-insert)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "U" (lambda ()
                                        (interactive)
                                        (beginning-of-line-text)
                                        (execute-kbd-macro "u")))
```

Is there an 'evil command to insert mode at start of line? Or a more elegant way to fire `'evil-insert` or run multiple commands?

Comment: What's wrong with `i` and `I`?

Comment: oh, I'm using Colemak keyboard layout, and switching from VIM to Spacemacs, so I have lots of keys customization and my muscle memory is very ingrained... https://github.com/quangv/.qv.space/blob/develop/.spacemacs#L311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In evil-mode `i` executes `evil-insert` and `I` executes `evil-insert-line`.

So the simplest rebinding would be:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "u" 'evil-insert)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "U" 'evil-insert-line)
```

Whenever you want to know which keys run which functions just press `C-h k` and then the keybinding of choice.